# m4 macro using variable number of tabs to line up a column

Tags: debugging, programming, m4

This is the macro I have so far:

```
define(`debug_macro', `
#ifndef $1_DEBUG
#define $1_DEBUG'forloop(`i',`1',eval(5-(len($1)/4+ifelse(eval(len($1)%4 == 0)), `0', `1')),`   ')dnl`0
#endif

')
```

The goal is to put the correct number of tabs between the `_DEBUG` and the `0` character so they all line up. There may be missing parens or quotes but hopefully you get the idea of where I'm going.

I'm using Xcode and have my tabs set to 4. Here are the changes I made to accommodate that:

```
divert(`-1')
# forloop(var, from, to, stmt)
define(`forloop',
`pushdef(`$1', `$2')_forloop(`$1', `$2', `$3', `$4')popdef(`$1')')
define(`_forloop',
`$4`'ifelse($1, `$3', ,
`define(`$1', incr($1))_forloop(`$1', `$2', `$3', `$4')')')
divert`'dnl
changecom()dnl
define(`debug_macro', `
#ifndef $1_DEBUG
#define $1_DEBUG`'forloop(`i', `1', ifelse(eval(len($1) >= 16), 1, 1, eval(5-(len($1)/4+ifelse(eval(len($1)%4 > 1), 0, `0', `1')))),`   ')0
#endif

')
changecom()dnl
```

Since I couldn't find 'forloop.m4' on my system I just included it. The division by 4 rounds so I added the check for when the remainder is greater than 1. I also change the run of spaces for a single tab character.

For the interested I use this macro to define constants I use to turn on debugging of different areas of my application. This file is checked into git. There is then a file that is personal and not checked in that looks something like this:

```
//#define NETWORK_DEBUG  1
```

The file is included in the myapp.pch file before including the above file. That way each programmer can have their own debug areas turned on or off as they please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to indent something is to use spaces, not tabs. Especially not tabs with a non-standard width (insofar as there is a standard width for tabs, it's 8).

The second-simplest way to indent something with tabs is to generate a file with spaces and call [`unexpand`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/unexpand.html) to replace spaces by tabs.

That being said, you can do it in m4, but you'll have to get more familiar with it. Build your expressions incrementally: get one piece to work, then move on to the next one.

`forloop` is not a standard m4 macro. I think you mean the [`forloop` macro presented in the GNU m4 manual](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/m4/manual/m4-1.4.17/html_node/Forloop.html#Forloop). This is sample code that ships with GNU m4 (the manual doesn't make this very clear); to use it in your code, you need to include it explicitly. Distributions may or may not ship it, so you'd better distribute it with your code.

There are several syntax problems in your code.

- You've left the call to `forloop` outside of any quotes, so it's evaluated at the time `define` is evaluated, not at the time `debug_macro` is evaluated.
- The `ifelse` macro doesn't choose based on the value of the first argument alone, compares its first two arguments — it's more of a case macro: the call should be `ifelse(…, 0, 0, 1)` or `ifelse(… == 0, 1, 0, 1)`.
- `#` starts a comment. M4 ignores everything after a comment. [Change the comment delimiter](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/m4/manual/m4-1.4.17/html_node/Changecom.html#Changecom) while you define the `debug_macro` macro.

The following code works as long as the argument isn't too long:

```
include(`/usr/share/doc/m4/examples/forloop.m4')dnl
changecom()dnl
define(`debug_macro', `
#ifndef $1_DEBUG
#define $1_DEBUG`'forloop(`i',`1',eval(5-(len($1)/4+ifelse(eval(len($1)%4), 0, `0', `1'))),`    ')0
#endif

')dnl
changecom('#')dnl
```

With an argument that causes the maximum loop index to become 0 or less, the loop is executed about 2<sup>32</sup> times (m4 uses 32-bit modulo arithmetic). You need an additional test in this case. Here's code that inserts a single tab when the argument is too long.

```
include(`/usr/share/doc/m4/examples/forloop.m4')dnl
changecom()dnl
define(`debug_macro', `
#ifndef $1_DEBUG
#define $1_DEBUG`'forloop(`i', `1', ifelse(eval(len($1) >= 16), 1, 1, eval(5-(len($1)/4+ifelse(eval(len($1)%4), 0, `0', `1')))),`       ')0
#endif

')dnl
changecom('#')dnl
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I ended modifying it slightly. I'm using Xcode and have my tabs set for 4. I've added to my question showing the changes.